# Add leading zeros to mySQL column

Tags: mysql

I've tried several solutions for this, but none seem to work. I have a zip code column thats `INT(10)`.

I need to convert it (to a VARCHAR, I guess) so that zip codes with a leading zero can be stored. Now they are "8721" instead of "08721".

I tried this:

```
SELECT RIGHT('0000'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,zip_code),5) AS NUM FROM p23data;
```

but I get an error:

`check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR,zip_code),5) AS NUM FROM p23data' at line 1`

I think the above is to create a new column, but I just need to update my existing `zip_code` column.

What am I not doing right here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`LPAD` will handle the leading zeros:

```
ALTER TABLE p23data CHANGE zip_code zip_code CHAR(5);
UPDATE p23data SET zip_code = LPAD(zip_code, 5, '0');
```

Comment: So, does this update my zip_code column or add a new one (or something else)?

Comment: Just selects the existing integer data, but formatted with leading zeros.

Comment: How do I update my zip_code column with the newly formatted numbers?

Comment: You'll have to change the data type to a character type (e.g. CHAR(5)), then run an update with the lpad

Comment: Your update did the trick. Thanks. Sorry my questions wasn't clear.

Comment: Wish I could up vote more than once. You saved me! Normal updates were not changing my value from 500 to 00500 because it saw the 2 values as the same even though I was using a varchar column. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score -1):

ZIP Codes are not `INT` ... they are five (or nine, or eleven) character strings that happen to be made up of nothing but the characters `0` through `9`.

Comment: I know, but that's how they were stored, so now I need to fix that.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Not clear from your wording that you didn't have control of that ... maybe throw "from an existing database" in there? In the meantime, my answer was accurate, so doesn't deserve a downvote (if it wasn't helpful, that's a novote not a downvote)